# Order vimrc options by occurence in VIM doc

Tags: vim

I'm struggling to order considerable amount of miscellaneous options in my `.vimrc` file.
Somewhere I saw an idea to order the `.vimrc` file by the order in which options are described in the VIM documentation.
So I wonder, is there any way to do this more or less automatically?

Comment: This appears to me as a very odd request. Order is all about retrieving items. The most accessible order to me would be alphabetically. The concept of "documentation order" is ill-defined since it may change without notice. Vim docs are living.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, don't really get what you are after or why you would want it but you can certainly group and sort all your `set ...` lines together.

First, move your cursor on the first line with:

```
gg
```

Then, mark the current line with:

```
ma
```

Then, group all your `set ...` instructions together at the top of the file with:

```
:g/^set/m0
```

Then, order them alphabetically with:

```
:.'a-sort
```

As for doing it "more or less automatically", pay attention to what you are doing instead.